# How to change arrowhead type?

Tags: syntax, graphviz

I want to simulate non-directional graphs with .dot. To that end, I want the arrowhead type to be "none". How do I set this?

```
"f" -> "t" [label=2],[arrowhead=none]
"m" -> "d" [label=0],[arrowhead=none]
```

The above is not working.

Comment: I note that the documentation I found (https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html) has `arrowType` instead of `arrowhead`. `arrowhead` works and `arrowType` does not. Apparently a documentation bug.

Answer (score -13, accepted):

Use `headport` instead of `arrowhead`. Read the [dot guide](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf).

Comment: Headport controls where the arrowhead attaches to the node, not the arrowhead shape.

Answer (score 37):

```
"f" -> "t" [label=2, arrowhead=none]
```

For example:

```
digraph g {
  rankdir="LR";
  dpi=300;
  node[
    fontname="Arial",
    shape="square",
    fixedsize=false,
    width=1.809,
    style=rounded
  ];

  edge [
    arrowhead="none"
  ];

  Node1 -> Node2;
  Node2 -> Node3;
  Node3 -> Node4;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Another nice way is to use the 'dir' attribute:

```
   "f" -> "t" [label=2 dir=none]
   "m" -> "d" [label=0 dir=none]
```

See also http://martin-loetzsch.de/DOTML/dir.html

Comment: This is nice because the "dir" attribute is shorter than "arrowhead".

Answer (score 11):

You can change the arrow head either *locally* or *globally*.

```
digraph G
{
    edge[arrowhead="odiamond"]; // Globally

    A -> B
    A -> C [arrowhead="vee"]; // Locally
    C -> D
    C -> E
}
```

You can test it on  [GraphvizFiddle](http://stamm-wilbrandt.de/GraphvizFiddle/)

All possible values could be found [Here](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#k:arrowType)

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to search how to set the arrowhead style globally and this helped!

Answer (score 9):

If you don't have to create a `digraph`, you can use a `graph`:

1. Replace `digraph {` on the top of your dot file by `graph {`.
2. Change your node relationships to: `a -- b;`

Answer (score 6):

```
"f" -> "t" [label=2 arrowhead=none]
"m" -> "d" [label=0 arrowhead=none]
```